# Unmet dependencies for libxcb-xinerama0

Tags: dependencies

trying to install bspwm I use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0-dev
```

I've followed the directions exactly and added the repositories listed, however I get the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxcb-xinerama0-dev : Depends: libxcb-xinerama0 (= 1.11.1-1ubuntu1) but 1.12-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: try this `sudo apt -f install libxcb-xinerama0-dev`

Comment: @George still didn't work, same error.

Comment: try `sudo apt -f install`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aptitude` to install the package as it will suggest the solution to unmet dependencies problems

install via apt `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

then install the package:

`sudo aptitude install libxcb-xinerama0-dev`

where `aptitude` will suggest the solutions to resolve the problem,what you should do is to choose the right one that you think will solve your problem.

Comment: glad it helped :)!